# Mac OSX, Emacs 24.2 and nrepl.el not working

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen

I'm using [nrepl.el](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider), [Emacs 24.2](https://emacsformacosx.com/). My S.O version is OS X Lion 10.7.5.

Running the command `[M-x] nrepl` after start a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) session through [lein](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) `(:~ $ lein repl)` i am able to connect to it but if i try to use `[M-x] nrepl-jack-in` i get the message bellow:

> error in process sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: /bin/bash:
> lein: command not found

I installed leiningen using the [instructions in the main site](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen#installation) and reinstalled it using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) with the command `brew install leiningen --devel` but both methods give me the same error.

Adding the path `/usr/loca/bin` to emacs `exec-path` list or trying to configure `nrepl.el` variable `nrepl-lein-command` to point to the full path of my lein installation does not help.

My emacs configuration can be found here: https://github.com/khaoz/emacs-files

What i'm doing wrong ?

Thanks :)

Comment: are you by chance on a Mac and staring emacs not from the command line?

Comment: no. I start it from spotlight.

Comment: Just a warning in advance, if you're ever planning to use ac-nrepl - at least at the moment it seems to sometimes do wonky things when you started the server with nrepl-jack-in. Maybe they fixed this by now, just recall it if you run into problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

for those of you landing on this question who are using a Mac:

lein needs to be on the path as seen by Emacs. This can be done by starting Emacs from bash

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs project.clj
```

then: 
 <kbd>M-x</kbd> nrepl-jack-in

If this solves the problem you can configure emacs to use the correct path by following [these instructions](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsApp#toc2)

Comment: Yep. Your answer is right. But is there a way to start emacs from spotlight or dock and get `nrepl-jack-in` to work ?

Comment: Just to add more information, instead of editing the system file `/etc/profile`, creating or changing the file `~/.profile` also works but it will apply the change only for the current user.

Comment: I just had this exact problem on Ubuntu too. Thanks Arthur.

Comment: as a folowup nrepl mode is being replaced by cider-mode. so it's M-x cider-jack-in now though this answer should apply equally well to cider

Answer (score 13):

While @Arthur is correct a much simpler solution to your problem would be to install the [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) Emacs extension. It will copy your shell `PATH` (and `MANPATH`) to Emacs automatically and fairly reliably. This means that the `PATH` would be correct no matter where you started Emacs from (spotlight included).

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing this error in Linux, you may need to set your PATH in ~/.bash_profile instead of ~/.bashrc when running emacs from the menu instead of the shell.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this:

```
;; set the path as terminal path [http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2011-10/msg00237.html]
(setq explicit-bash-args (list "--login" "-i"))

;; fix the PATH variable for GUI [http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/emacs.html#osx] 

(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  (let ((path-from-shell
         (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL -i -l -c 'echo $PATH'")))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))

(when window-system (set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH))
```