# Can't launch `lein` REPL in Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen

In Emacs, when using `clojure-mode`, I ought to be able to launch a REPL with `C-c C-z`. Whenever I try, though, I get the error:

```
Searching for program: no such file or directory: lein
```

I have `lein` installed in `/usr/local/bin` (via `brew`) and `/usr/local/bin` is in my `PATH` (even Emacs says so, via `eval-expression (getenv "PATH")`).

What am I missing?

Comment: A have made a question like yours here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243048/mac-osx-emacs-24-2-and-nrepl-el-not-working. Maybe the answare could help you. ;)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ah! The `PATH` environment variable isn't the end-all and be-all of emacs search paths. There's also the "exec-path". It apparently does [mostly the same thing but not exactly](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath).

Anyway, adding:

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/bin")
```

To my `.emacs.d/init.el` (or `.emacs` if that's how you roll) cleared things up for me. The doc linked above suggests something a little more comprehensive, like:

```
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/usr/local/bin"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))
```

I'd try the (simpler) `add-to-list`, first. But YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and started to investigate what was wrong.
I soon discovered my exec-path looked like this (simplified example):

```
("/usr/local/bin /bin /sbin").
```

It was a list with just one long string instead of a list of separate paths.
My env PATH variable looked exactly the same. Obviously the problem was coming from my shell.

I use fish-shell. It's PATH variable separator is just a space.
The exec-path-from-shell package I use can't parse it.
I fixed it by appending this to my .emacs.d/init.el:

```
(setq exec-path (split-string (car exec-path)))
```

Update:
In the end it was an outdated exec-path-from-shell package. Use version 1.8. It works well with fish (and tcsh).