# Executing Clojure in Emacs with `cider-jack-in`

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen, read-eval-print-loop, cider

I'm trying to run Clojure emacs with cider package installed. 
I use Emacs 24.5.1 on Mac OS X 10.10.4.

I downloaded `lein` script and copied the script in ~/Dropbox/bin. 
I checked with `lein repl` that Clojure works fine.

cider package is installed with `M-x package-install`. I edited the `~/.emacs.d/init.el` to specify the lein script: `(add-to-list 'exec-path "~/Dropbox/bin")` with the hint from [Can't launch `lein` REPL in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671839/cant-launch-lein-repl-in-emacs).

However, when I started emacs and run `M-x cider-jack-in`, I have this error message:

[image]

When I started `lein repl` and executed `M-x cider-connect` (http://xahlee.info/clojure/clojure_emacs_cider.html), I can have the cider-repl running in Emacs.

[image]

What might be wrong?

Comment: To make it easier for other people who have run into the same or similar problem, it's usually better to post error messages as text that can be indexed by a search engine, vs. as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another easy solution is to just use homebrew. While homebrew is overkill just for installing lein, if you already use it, then all you need to do is run

```
brew update
brew install leiningen
```

and your done. I use homebrew to install emacs and some other useful apps, so I already have it on my system.

Comment: the lein from brew causes an issue, I updated my post. +1 for letting me know about installing lein with brew though.

Comment: Updating brew's leiningen formula installs version 2.5.3, and all the issues are gone. I think using leiningen is the simplest/easiest/best way in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 16):

The quickest fix was to symbolically link lein to the path where Emacs can find it. This line of code fixed the issue.

```
sudo ln -s ~/Dropbox/bin/lein /usr/local/bin/lein
```

I summarized the steps to install the cider package for running Clojure on emacs without any errors or warnings.

cider - https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider

#### Installation

- Download lein https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein

  - I copied the file ~/Dropbox/bin after making it executable.
- It looks like that /usr/local/bin is not the path that Emacs finds the binary automatically, so I had to set it up.

  - Run `sudo ln -s ~/Dropbox/bin/lein /usr/local/bin/lein`
  - Update `~/.emacs.d/init.el` to specify the location of lein script:

    - `(add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/local/bin")`
- Update `~/.lein/profiles.clj`

  - [Installation of cider-nrepl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399136/installation-of-cider-nrepl)
  - `{:user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.10.0-SNAPSHOT"]]}}`
  - run `lein deps`

#### Errors and solutions

- If error `The lein executable (specified by`cider-lein-command' or `cider-boot-command') isn't on your exec-path` occurs:

  - make the symbolic link, and update the `init.el` as is explained.
- If error "Symbol's function definition is void: clojure-project-dir" occurs, it's because of the package version mismatch.

  - http://www.braveclojure.com/using-emacs-with-clojure/
  - delete the old packages in `~/emacs.d/elpa`

    - clojure-mode
    - cider-*
  - Then, run `package-install` in Emacs

    - clojure-mode
    - cider

Now, all the warnings are gone.

[image]

#### References

- [Can't launch `lein` REPL in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671839/cant-launch-lein-repl-in-emacs)
- [Executing Clojure in Emacs with `cider-jack-in`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150574/executing-clojure-in-emacs-with-cider-jack-in)
- cider - https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider

### Added

For Mac OS X, `brew install leiningen` can install the lein, but this caused an issue as in [How to upgrade nrepl version of leiningen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688721/how-to-upgrade-nrepl-version-of-leiningen). This is the message from the lein brew.

```
nREPL server started on port 61216 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:61216
REPL-y 0.3.5, nREPL 0.2.6
Clojure 1.6.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_45-b14
```

I had to use the lein from the lein site to get the correct version of tools.

```
Retrieving org/clojure/clojure/1.2.0/clojure-1.2.0.pom from central
nREPL server started on port 61279 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:61279
REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.7
Clojure 1.7.0
```